# Word sensor is not working in Xcode Editor

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

When I write forcefully "Any UI" then I face compiler error.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var mybutton  =  UILabel()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? You need to get more clear about your problem.

Comment: if i wrote Any UIComponent just Like (uilabel, uibutton Etc) then i got compiler error

Comment: Xcode is still in beta with Swift and is not fully compatible with autocompletion yet.